# Custom search for entire site collection in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search

I want to create custom search using c# for share point site collection. In that
site collection I have some document libraries are there. It is like keyword based search. I want to search based on the keywords. It's like a OOTB search but I want custom code using C#
Plz help me.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the OOTB search?

Comment: I have asp.net application. From that application i uploaded some documents to share point server. The documents will be saved in to the share point server. From share point site we can use OOTB search. But here i want to use search from asp.net application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty solid MSDN article with C# examples of using the search API:

[Using the SharePoint search Query APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn423226.aspx)